# Fast converting std::chrono::time_point to/from std::string

Tags: c++, string, datetime, c++17, c++-chrono

How to **locale-free** convert `std::chrono::time_point` to/from `std::string` of a **predefined** date-time format `YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.zzzzzzzzz`?

[For me it turned out](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/156695/converting-stdchronotime-point-to-from-stdstring) that the only way is to use `std::get_time` and `std::put_time` with `std::itringstream` and `std::ostringstream`, but:

- the first two have C-style interface with `std::tm` and `time_t` (bearable)
- the last two are slow and `std::locale` dependent (crucial).

Any other alternatives?

Third party libraries can also be considered. I looked at `boost::posix_time::ptime` but seams it is also locale-dependent, plus it is slower and less generic than `std::chrono::time_point`.

Comment: This is basically a "find me a library" question. But... It turns out that there is one proposed for C++20 standardization. Made by Howard Hinnant, who was behind the `chrono` standard library component. He was even nice enough to [implement it for us](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) ;).

Comment: @NicolBolas, why not turn that into an answer?

Comment: @D_N: Because this is a question that should be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know if it is fast enough for you, but:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    std::cout << std::chrono::system_clock::now() << '\n';
}
```

Just output for me:

```
2017-03-02 17:04:26.813110
```

This is a library I've written.  It is free, open-source, and the `"date.h"` part is header-only.  There is [full documentation](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html), and even video tutorials, all linked off of the [GitHub page](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).

There are fairly extensive formatting and parsing options, as well as many other features which make it safe and easy to do time and calendrical computations.

Additionally, if this formatting isn't fast enough for you, the library is flexibly layered so that you could interact with it at a lower-level and easily write your own I/O.  For example here is how you can get *all* of the field types as `int` from a `system_clock::time_point` to microseconds precision:

```
#include "date.h"

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto t = system_clock::now();

    // Convert system_clock::time_point to days-precision time_point
    auto sd = floor<days>(t);
    // Create time_of_day
    auto tod = make_time(t - sd);
    // Create year_month_day
    year_month_day ymd = sd;

    // Extract field types as int
    int y = int{ymd.year()}; // Note 1
    int m = unsigned{ymd.month()};
    int d = unsigned{ymd.day()};
    int h = tod.hours().count();
    int M = tod.minutes().count();
    int s = tod.seconds().count();
    int us = duration_cast<microseconds>(tod.subseconds()).count();
}
```

Now you can format these `int`s however you want.

*Note 1:* Prior to gcc-6.1 there's a compiler bug concerning `{}` here. Use `()` instead to workaround the compiler bug.

Going the reverse direction (from `int`s to `system_clock::time_point`) is even easier:

```
#include "date.h"

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    int y = 2017;
    int m = 3;
    int d = 2;
    int h = 15;
    int M = 33;
    int s = 55;
    int us = 123456;

    // Convert field values to system_clock::time_point
    system_clock::time_point t = sys_days(year{y}/m/d) + hours{h} + minutes{M} +
                                 seconds{s} + microseconds{us};
}
```

Parse your `int`s however you want and then you can form a `system_clock::time_point` in a single statement.

The library has an active user community which helps maintain it on several platforms.

Comment: I am looking for a kind of overload for `std::chrono::time_point` of C++17 proposed locale-independent conversion functions `std::from_chars` and `std::to_chars`. The streams are locale-dependent so `"chrono_io.h"` will not help.

Comment: @Vahagn:  Worst case scenario:  You can use this library just for the `time_point` to `y/m/d h:m:s` conversion (and vice-versa) and I/O the integral values of each of those fields.  This library is a type-safe wrapper of these very efficient (non-iterative) conversion functions:  http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html